# Why does the Datagridcombobox empty when you choose another row

Tags: c#, combobox, datagrid

Im just wondering if anybody knows why a datagrid's combobox would disappear when you click another row.

basically the comboboxes look like they are hidden, and when you click the empty space, it appears and then you can choose a value.

but once you choose another row, it disappears again.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: complete example plz

Comment: thats basically all of it...the data-binding cant have anything to do with invisible comboboxes.

Comment: you should consider making a minimum example so that ppl can copy paste and run on their machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use CellTemplate instead of CellEditingTemplate.

Property CellEditingTemplate gets or sets the template to use to display the contents of a cell that is in editing mode.

Property CellTemplate gets or sets the template to use to display the contents of a cell that is not in editing mode.

Comment: If i could upvote this comment x1000 i would...i was still sitting on this and not knowing what was wrong...I would buy you a beer if i could !